# Weird code formatting on Chrome iPhone "Request desktop site"

Tags: bug, design, markdown

There is some weird code formatting in SO. The try is one space back than what it should be.

Here's what it displays for a `try` keyword:

[image: code]

And what it displays in the edit column:

[image: edit page]

Original page: [Function with throws doesn't exit the function with executes trow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450126/function-with-throws-doesnt-exit-the-function-with-executes-trow/42450765#42450765)

Note: I am using "request desktop site" function on Chrome on iPhone

Other questions also have this problem:

[Swift do-try-catch syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720497/swift-do-try-catch-syntax)  `throw` is indented by half a space more:

[image: bug]

I am seeing it like this in Safari on iPad:

[image]

This questions markdown is displayed extremely incorrectly:

What I am seeing:

[image]

What it looks like in the edit column:

[image]

Conclusion: something is wrong with code formatting in iPhone Chrome with "request desktop site"

Comment: That's not what it looks like to me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kskrimbqfenlw6q/Screenshot%202017-02-24%2021.49.37.png?dl=0

Comment: Note: I am using chrome on iphone with "request desktop site" turned on, sorry for not clarifying

Comment: I'm still seeing it: http://imgur.com/PQtx8Cp

Comment: Is there a tab character in there? That could account for the formatting oddities between platforms.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Actually can you type tabs on SO? I tried clicking the tab button and it just focused on the 'post answer' button. I only use spaces in my answers.

Comment: You can paste tabs. Just a guess as it doesn't seem to make much sense that it would render spaces differently in a monospace font... I'm not sure they actually support the desktop site on mobile.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan uhhh.. ok